# Expand a number

Tags: code-golf, number

## Expand a number

Your task is to expand an integer greater than 0 in the following manner:

Split the number into decimal digits and for each digit generate a list according to these rules:

- if the digit is odd, the list starts with the digit and goes down to 1;
- if the digit is even, the list starts with the digit and goes up to 9.
- if the digit is 0, the list is empty.

Write down the lists for the odd numbers below the digits, and above for the even ones. Then top-align the columns and collect the digits in each row to make integers. As a final step add up the numbers to find the expansion of the  number.

Here's an example of the above rules applied to 34607:

```
 9          
 8          
 79         
 68         
 57         
346 7 ->  399 7 -> 3997 -> 9418
2   6     288 6    2886
1   5     177 5    1775
    4      66 4     664
    3      5  3      53
    2      4  2      42 
    1         1       1
```

Here are the test cases:

```
1: 1
2: 44
3: 6
44: 429
217: 1270
911: 947
2345: 26114
20067: 3450
34875632: 70664504
9348765347634763: 18406119382875401
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answers in bytes in each language win.

Comment: Can we take input as a string? Or as an array of digits?

Comment: @Arnauld It must be an integer, and to split it to digits with your program/function

Comment: @GalenIvanov But if input is from stdin, I suppose that's ok (even though technically a string), right?

Comment: @Adám Yes, technically it's a string, so that's ok.

Comment: And here I thought it would be an expansion like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90hie.jpg).

Comment: @Engineer Toast Yes, something like this :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Dḟ0RrḂ?€9UZḌS
```

A monadic link taking and returning positive integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4Y75BkFFD3c02T9qWmMZGvVwR0/w////jQwMzMwB)** or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4Y75BkFFD3c02T9qWmMZGvVwR0/w/6N7DrcDue7//0cb6hjpGOuYmOgYGZrrWBoCucYmpjpGBgZm5jrGJhbmpmbGRjqWIJaZqbGJuRkYxwIA).

#### How?

```
Dḟ0RrḂ?€9UZḌS - Link: positive integer           e.g. 702
D             - cast to a decimal list                [7,0,2]
  0           - literal zero                          0
 ḟ            - filter discard                        [7,2]
        9     - literal nine
       €      - for each:
      ?       -   if:
     Ḃ        -   ...condition: bit (modulo by 2)      1              ,0
   R          -   ...then: range ([1,...n])            [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],n/a
    r         -   ...else: inclusive range ([n,...9])  n/a            ,[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
         U    - upend                                 [[7,6,5,4,3,2,1],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2]]
          Z   - transpose                             [[7,9],[6,8],[5,7],[4,6],[3,5],[2,4],[1,3],2]
           Ḍ  - cast from decimal lists               [79,68,57,46,35,24,13,2]
            S - sum                                   324
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>68</s>  66 bytes

```perl6
{sum roundrobin(.comb».&{$_%2??($_...1)!!(9...+$_) if +$_})».join}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##TY7daoNAEIXv5ykmwQbF1Oyu6/pHmt72vpcFaXQDFl3Fn9IiPlnv@mJ2TAPtxTDDOd85TKu7Si1jr/FdeXkK9Sfu8qbQeFymfqyxa0ZTdM25NLaXN/X5@8vbTVZ2J04n28o8z@POZmPHdLhW5mB5QdqzQ9hbU5p5ob7HQfcDJkesSqN7ctYe@/BSuIeVezJDCusDz4Sl0FavBt1rJgW4NN0tf/@AtlWadhz2aOmPVueDLhycALHscX35Zjv//D1uf8XkT9vCvPAEOYgEpQQ/QQVS0i1iEDwkR4QMYk5MLEMQvgwSFIpzCYIxRQApDHwZhYHyqSRkSpEiIV41FfgyVNehqkgySsZ@JIiWjP8A)

```perl6
{sum roundrobin(.comb».&{[R,] $_%2??1..$_!!$_..9 if +$_})».join}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##VY7LTsMwEEX38xXTKlSJWlzbcZyXStmyRewARTRxpaDWifJAoKhfxo4fC5NSCVhYss4999q1aQ567FuDb5rlKRw/cJFXhcHNOLT9EZuqt0VT7Urrsrw67r4@2WJ4vF89o5Ndye1WMOZks5mTMRZjucelk508kl6r0p5GWrvtTNthssFDaU1LybTirp@K5Xry7myXwvT8A2kp1IcXi8tzJwXYV82lf32DrlPauu9W6Jj32uSdKTwcALEocPrwJfZSQmX7D/2prHD@A5NfNofTKBIUIBNUCvwENShFdxmDFCElMuQQC3JiFYL0VZCg1EIokJxrEohw8FUUBtqnkZBrTURBPDEd@CrU50NTkeLUjP1Ikq24@AY)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  sum

    roundrobin( # grab from the sub lists in a round robin fashion

      .comb\             # split the input into digits
      ».&{               # for each digit do this

        [R,]             # reduce with reversed &infix:«,» (shorter than reverse)

              $_ % 2     # is the digit not divisible by 2?
          ??  1  .. $_   # from 1 to the digit
          !!  $_ ..  9   # from the digit to 9

        if +$_           # only do the above if the current digit isn't 0
                         # (has the effect of removing 0 from the list)
     }

    )».join     # join each of the sub-lists from roundrobin
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 39 bytes

Full program body. Prompts for input from STDIN. Prints result to STDOUT.

```apl
+/10⊥¨0~⍨¨↓⍉↑{2|⍵:⌽⍳⍵⋄×⍵:⌽⍵,⍵↓⍳9⋄⍬}¨⍎¨⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3PSsQwEMbvfYq562LSpOl273pefINo3SVQm2IrKP45Sf2bRRHxpDehB2/LHr2sbzIv0p1WEJrAhPl@830zushG6bnO7LzFxdvePtbPPBzHgO4DqBkdmArSo0NzrDOYZVZXZUC@6ZR8QgL0vuLE5BWcFlBZIJiaualKsDMaULI0Ng/w7nb3rNB52m7tcIYPX@uGXaNr1g3Wr@jusX65CC/RrSb49INuSR0@3vy@/5PVdoc67zKhCbrvK8q6Rfd9trS@hf79XQmEVCwOBogPZTiUYiil9Nzc25Zwf5@QkUcYU15KyHEcKeHdTjqsIiFj1dcG)

To display the last test case correctly, `⎕FR` (**F**loating-point **R**epresentation) has been set to 128-bit Decimal and `⎕PP` (**P**rint **P**recision) has been set to 34 digits.

`⍞` prompt for text input from STDIN

`⍎¨` execute each (gets each digit as a number)

`{`…`}¨` for each element, apply the following function where the argument is represented by `⍵`:

`2|⍵:` if odd (lit. "if" division remainder when divided by 2), then:

`⌽` reverse

`⍳` the **ɩ**ntegers from 1 until

`⍵` the argument

`⋄` else

`×⍵:` if the argument is positive (lit. "if" signum), then:

`⌽` reverse

`⍵` the argument

`,` followed by

`⍵` argument

`↓` elements dropped from

`⍳9` the the **ɩ**ntegers from 1 until 9

`⋄` else

`⍬` empty list

`↑` mix (combine) this list of lists into a single matrix, padding with zeros on the right

`⍉` transpose

`↓` split this matrix into a list of lists

`0~⍨¨` remove all zeros from each list

`10⊥¨` convert each from base-10 to normal numbers (this collects the digits)

`+/` sum the numbers

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. 
Just to let you know that I discovered code golf after watching you in the APL code golf video.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>88</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

```js
f=(n,k=0)=>k<9&&+[...n+''].map(x=>+x&&(x=x&1?x:9-k<x||9)>k?x-k:'').join``+f(n,k+1)
```

#### Note

`9 - k < x || 9` saves a byte over `9 - k >= x && 9` but generates `1` instead of `0` if the inequality is verified. It would be a problem if it leaded to `1 > k`, triggering the wrong path in the outer ternary. But it would mean that `k = 0` and therefore `9 - k = 9`, so we can't possibly have `9 - k < x` at the same time.

#### Test cases

NB: Removed the last test case which exceeds JS number precision.

```js
f=(n,k=0)=>k<9&&+[...n+''].map(x=>+x&&(x=x&1?x:9-k<x||9)>k?x-k:'').join``+f(n,k+1)

console.log(f(1))                // 1
console.log(f(2))                // 44
console.log(f(3))                // 6
console.log(f(44))               // 429
console.log(f(217))              // 1270
console.log(f(911))              // 947
console.log(f(2345))             // 26114
console.log(f(20067))            // 3450
console.log(f(34875632))         // 70664504
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
ì f ®òZu ª9 wÃy xì
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=7CBmIK7yWnUgqjkgd8N5IHjs&input=MzQ4NzU2MzI=)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 11, <s>210</s> <s>209</s> <s>191</s> 181 bytes

```java
n->{long r=0;var a="0".repeat(9).split("");for(int d:(n+"").getBytes())for(int k=0,x=d-48,y=9;x>0&(k<1||(d%2<1?y-->x:x-->1));a[k++]+=d%2<1?y:x);for(var q:a)r+=new Long(q);return r;}
```

Ok, this took quite a while (mainly because I made a mistake at first, so had to write down each step to better understand what I did wrong). Can most likely be golfed some more.

-18 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##XVJNj4IwEL37KyYku2mDEBBEoeIme3a9eDQeulANgkVLZSHqb3cLsofuodO8N52PN9Mjral1TPNnUtCqgi@a8dsIIOOSiT1NGKw7CFCU/AAJ6i@OieIeI2UqSWWWwBo4xPDk1vLWvxCxQ2oqgMaGY9iCnRmVKMR2dS4yiQwDk30pkCoCaYS4qQj7wORnK1mFMP7z5bEzbuLU8ufjNg5Js3TeUb5w73eUvk0W7kdrWcsmapR1MSZ0m5vmzowHX9S8inRtXCKKhRlz9gMr1R66YCKYvAoOgjyepBNyvn4XSsigpy6zFE5qFmgjRcYP2x1Q/BqEalEid9WPYEATDXka8n39qTvTcOj@S@X5U51wnEAP8fzA0ZmJP59NA09vI/QUG0w9fxb0ZzUsDaBTK7KaSqbJ7aP67RWD1E1bSXayy6u0VQCXBUeFaURgmNxWXwEPGR/PXw)

```java
n->{                             // Method with long as both parameter and return-type
  long r=0;                      //  Result-long `r`, starting at 0
  var a="0".repeat(9).split(""); //  String array `a`, filled with nine String zeroes
  for(int d:(n+"").getBytes())   //  Cast the input to a String,
                                 //   and loop over its codepoints as integers:
    for(int k=0,                 //   Row-index `k`, starting at
        x=d-48,                  //   Temp integer `x`, set to the current digit
        y=9                      //   Temp integer `y`, set to 9
        ;                        //   Inner loop, if:
         x>0                     //     The current digit is not a 0,
          &(k<1                  //     and if this is the first iteration,
             ||(d%2<1?           //     or if the digit is even:
                 y-->x           //      And `y` is larger than the digit
                                 //      (and afterwards decrease `y` by 1 with `y--`)
                :                //     or if the digit is odd:
                 x-->1));        //      And `x` is larger than 1
                                 //      (and afterwards decrease `x` by 1 with `x--`)
      a[k++]+=                   //    Append the current row with:
                                 //    (and afterwards increase `k` by 1 with `k++`)
       d%2<1?                    //     If the digit is even:
        y                        //      Append the row with `y`
       :                         //     Else (the digit is odd):
        x);                      //      Append the row with `x`
  for(var q:a)                   //  Loop over the String rows in the array:
    r+=new Long(q);              //   Convert it to a long, and add it to the result-sum
  return r;}                     //  Return the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 28 bytes

```
J_MS(RV{a?a%2?\,aa,tl}Ma)ZDx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fK943WCMorDrRPlHVyD5GJzFRpySn1jdRM8ql4v///8YmZgbmAA)

#### Explanation

```
                      Ma      Map this function to the digits of the 1st cmdline arg:
        a?                     If digit != 0:
          a%2?                  If digit is odd:
              \,a                Inclusive-range(digit)
                 a,t            Else (digit is even), range from digit to 10 (exclusive)
                    l          Else (digit is 0), empty list
     RV{             }         Apply reverse to the result before returning it
                              This gives us a list of lists like [9 8 7 6] or [3 2 1]
    (                   )ZDx  Zip, with a default value of empty string
J_MS                          Use map-sum to join each sublist and sum the results
                              Autoprint (implicit)
```

How the steps proceed with `34607` as the argument:

```
34607
[[1 2 3] [4 5 6 7 8 9] [6 7 8 9] [] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]
[[3 2 1] [9 8 7 6 5 4] [9 8 7 6] [] [7 6 5 4 3 2 1]]
[[3 9 9 "" 7] [2 8 8 "" 6] [1 7 7 "" 5] ["" 6 6 "" 4] ["" 5 "" "" 3] ["" 4 "" "" 2] ["" "" "" "" 1]]
[3997 2886 1775 664 53 42 1]
9418
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>153</s> 146 bytes

```r
function(n,m=n%/%10^(nchar(n):0)%%10)sum(strtoi(apply(sapply(m[m>0],function(x)c(r<-"if"(x%%2,x:1,9:x),rep("",9-sum(r|1)))),1,paste,collapse="")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzRCsIgFEB/JQThXrgjrSg2tn4kCkQmCepEHRj077YIOi8HzsNJzezGrpk16GKXAIH8FPieS/GAoJ8qQcBBIN8C5tVDLqksFlSM7gX5J3/zV3Gn/6OihjR2zBoGlfMD1UFSP1SkNEdgjPruu0pviRskKapcZtKLcyrmeWJsy83A8XQWF2wf)

<s>Sometimes, I can't tell if I'm just garbage at golfing, or if R is....</s> It's definitely me, saved 7 bytes thanks to user2390246, who reminded me of another way to extract digits (that I suggested myself).

You may replace `strtoi` with `as.double` to get `18406718084351604` for the last test case (which is wrong); R only has 32-bit integers.

Comment: You can save a bit by taking n as an integer and converting to digits using one of your tricks! [146 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYzdCsIgGEDvewxB@IQvchXFRutFosBMmeAf6sBB726LoHNz4Fyc1Kx5JpEWcKpM4ZXZRo9Nz14WEzx4dKOnO9rxB3g5iQSeDZzRNbA8O8gllWBAxGgXyD@5m7vyO/4flUlIly0xmkCldI916LAfKsOkIhCC/fa7Su@OrWCHUeSiUAZrRcxqJGTNTcPheOJn1j4)

Comment: @user2390246 you know, I tried that, but I think I was fixated on using the implicit conversion to  `character->int` when I called `:` and then used `strtoi` anyway!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 23 bytes

```
siRT.Tm*!!d@,}9d}d1dsMz
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=siRT.Tm%2a%21%21d%40%2C%7D9d%7Dd1dsMz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A44%0A217%0A911%0A2345%0A20067%0A34875632%0A9348765347634763&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>106</s> 104 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f n=sum$map read$transpose$[reverse$[[c..'9'],['1'..c]]!!mod(read[c])2|c<-show n,c>'0']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NasMwEITv@xQbCDgBWehnLVmi6anH9gmMD8JxiEn8g@y2h7bP7sqBXnpYmJ3d@eYa5lt7v69r109jXPAlLIG/dvMCFxxO83u/78OEsQ3n/RLDME/j3O6r2H60cRNVw3nmsppVmcw4b@p6t@vH82ELVE19VN/NUz5fx08cWPOciaxe@9ANeMKEfcPDFLthQY6XI1aSKaYZEVPSMifTqqlgSghjmabSFkYr5jZlCk3WPKaGrxykRwnKIxFojwaIklYOEihdlBWQcB4dWdiYHpWRkuCB9pgcAX8FHq0wJjkE/6sSqiSRkk6XKn2TkJD/rL8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 120 + 1 (`-a`) = 121 bytes

```perl
$p=y/01357/ /r;$n=y/02468/ /r;map{$p=~s/9/ /g;$p=~s/\d/$&+1/ge;$n=~s/\d/$&-1/ge;$n=~s/0/ /g;@F=($p,@F,$n)}0..7;say for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lwLZS38DQ2NRcX0G/yFolD8Q1MjGzAHNzEwuqgSrqivUtgfx0awg7JkVfRU3bUD89FaQeJqCLJGAAVu3gZquhUqDj4KajkqdZa6CnZ25dnFipkJZf5OD2/7@hkbGJqZm5haXBv/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv91EwE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 131 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(int(''.join(`n`for n in l if n))for l in map(None,*[range(n and(n%2*n or 9),(n%2<1)*~-n,-1)for n in map(int,`n*10`)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BDoIwDIbve4peDCsphrEBYtRH8AXUhBlEZ6AQ1IMXXx03Dx7atN//9@/4ft4GzuZ2e5w7258bC7x@vHrp@CmjaHkfHMua63aYgMExdOBaYMQAugB6O8r9wBeKD5Pl60UyWG4kL7KYwZsqpLBsFMafhClR@M8Kp/4P1RyrtMYT4hw057WDIpGR0CSM8ZMqSVQqMG1y39O08ESbVZkX2vuqMBa5NmXxK3FaCxgnHw6OIEp2EUErHc5f)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0KεDÈi9ŸëL]íõζJO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//zBLzrVEw4hpOcW4w6tMXcOtw7XOtkpP//8zNDYwNw) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/A@9zW10Od2RaHt1xeLVPbe3htYe3ntvm5f9f53@0oY6RjrGOiYmOkaG5jqUhkGtsYqpjZGBgZq5jbGJhbmpmbKRjCWKZmRqbmJuBcSwA).

Or alternatively:

```
0KεDÈ8*>Ÿ{R}õζJO
0Kε9Ÿ¬L‚yèR}õζJO
```

**Explanation:**

```python
0K        # Remove all 0s from the (implicit) input-integer
  ε       #  Map each digit to:
   D      #   Duplicate the digit
    Èi    #   If it's even:
      9Ÿ  #    Pop and push a list in the range [digit, 9]
     ë    #   Else (the digit is odd):
      L   #    Pop and push a list in the range [1, digit]
  ]       # Close both the if-else statement and map
   í      # Reverse each inner ranged list
     ζ    # Zip/transpose, swapping rows and columns,
    õ     # with an empty string as filler
      J   # Join each inner list together
       O  # And sum that list
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 39 bytes

```
riXX:nz{J2dv{{9r@}{ro}}che!<-}m[tp)im++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/KDMiwiqvqtrLKKWsutqyyKG2uii/tjY5I1XRRrc2N7qkQDMzV1v7/39jEzMDcwA)

```
ri      #Read as int
XX      #Return list of digits
:nz     #Filter for non-zero
{
 J2dv   #Divisible by 2?
 {
  {9r@} #Range a, 9
  {ro}  #Range 1, a
 }che!  #Run based on if divisible
 <-     #Reverse the range
}m[     #Apply to each digit
tp      #Transpose digits
)im     #Join each list into single int
++      #Sum each int
```